# Data does not log to console with useEffect after app reload; data only logs with app save

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-hooks

I would like some help with this.
I am trying to query my cloud-based firestore db and print out selected items.

The data structure as follows:

```
{
      "name": "projects/myapp/databases/(default)/documents/place/wr8MvJQsmGI8QTbGJ3po",
      "fields": {
        "title": {
          "stringValue": "Hotel"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2022-10-14T08:32:16.920093Z",
      "updateTime": "2022-10-14T08:32:16.920093Z"
    },
```

My import statements:

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../../config';
```

My function:

```
const AutoSearch = () => {
  const [returnedData, setReturnedData] = useState('');

  let singleItems = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const q = query(collection(db, 'place'), where('title', '!=', null));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        singleItems.push(doc.data().title);
        setReturnedData(singleItems);
      });
    };
    loadData();
    console.log(returnedData);
  }, []);

// other code follows.......
```

Problem:

The data array is not logged to console after app is reloaded; it only logs the data after app is saved

Comment: Put the `console.log` outside the `useEffect.`

Answer (score 0):

The `loadData` function declared `async` but the `useEffect` callback is still a synchronous function. In the effect callback `loadData` is called ***and then*** the initial `returnedData` state value is logged. The code is also incorrectly enqueueing state updates in the `.forEach` loop and overwriting any previously enqueued updates. Move `setReturnedData(singleItems);` outside the `.forEach` loop so a single update enqueues the entire `singleItems` array after it is populated.

Either log the `singleItems` value in `loadData` that you are updating the `returnedData` state to be:

```
const [returnedData, setReturnedData] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const loadData = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'place'), where('title', '!=', null));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const singleItems = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      singleItems.push(doc.data().title);
    });

    console.log(singleItems);
    setReturnedData(singleItems);
  };

  loadData();
}, []);
```

Or console log the `returnedData` state in a separate `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency:

```
const [returnedData, setReturnedData] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const loadData = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'place'), where('title', '!=', null));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const singleItems = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      singleItems.push(doc.data().title);
    });

    setReturnedData(singleItems);
  };

  loadData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(returnedData);
}, [returnedData]);
```

Comment: Thanks @ Drew. Works as intended. And thanks for clarifying other details.